# How can I turn my Macbook off before mailing it?

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook which I want to send to someone else as a gift.  All I have done with it so far is charge the battery and power the machine up to make sure it works!  It was bought new in 2009 but has remained unused all this time. The OS is Leopard 10.5?

I do NOT want to configure it/set anything up on it as the new owner will want to do all that. To all intents and purposes he is getting a brand new machine, I've just tested it to see if the power comes on and the battery is OK. But altough I closed the lid a small white light on the front of the case keeps coming on and off so obviously it is still 'on'.  I have no menu bar or anything else on the screen to turn it off that way because I didn't proceed after the set language screen on initial powering up.

Can I turn it off using the keyboard without doing any damage?  I need it to arrive in perfect working order in 2 days time after being couriered. He will expect to just be able to set it up on arrival.

Any help would be so gratefully received.
thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Can you not just remove the battery and ship it in the same package as the Macbook?

Comment: What is the exact model? MacBook? MacBook Pro? Late 2008? Early 2009? Mid 2009? Can you remove the battery even?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to remove the battery and securely package everything.

That way, there is no chance of it accidentally turning on during transit. All laptops with removable batteries are packaged this way.

Comment: This doesn't really work. All 2009 MacBook Pro models don't have removable batteries. Only the late 2008 unibody models have user-removable batteries. Some 15" models had user-removable batteries up until Mid 2009.

Comment: He mentioned MacBook, not MacBook Pro. My answer assumes it is a Macbook with a removable battery.

Comment: The question has a MacBook Pro tag too, that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to ship it with the battery installed, you can hold the power button for 4 seconds and it will power it down.  For extra security you could put a piece of a thin grocery store bag in the battery well before you install the battery - just leave enough outside so it will be obvious.  But with the cover closed it would be pretty hard for the machine to turn on accidentally.  Mine has never done that.